# There is more than one correct answer for function graph.

Tags: calculus, analysis

I saw question like this in Calculus book.

> The graph of the derivative of a function is given. Sketch the graphs
> of two functions that have the given derivative. (There is more than
> one correct answer.)

And I think myself how can I explain exactly why there is more than one correct answer? I know this:

Let f(x) and g(x) different function. But its derivatives can be same function. Is it enough for my question's answer. Or can we explain this with another way?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is an answer then so is $f(x)+C$ for any constant $C$.

Comment: If $g(x)=f(x)+c$ the two derivatives same.

Comment: An example is $f(x) = 5x^2 + 3x + 7$ and its derivative if $f'(x)=10x + 3$.  While $g(x) =5x^2 + 3x - 2$.  Its derivative if $g'(x)=10x+3=f'(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That answer is just a way of saying that it is true because it is true.

Say that if $f$ is a solution, then, for every number $K$, $f+K$ is also a solution.

Comment: No. That's the opposite of what I wrote. Further explanation **is** required, and I provided such an explanation in my answer.

Comment: oh, sorry! I understand now. thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.